# SSL Issue with Litle API jar - hostname in certificate didn't match: <208.70.177.61> != <prelive.litle.com>

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate with Vantiv Litle gateway. I downloaded integration jar files from their server. Trying to use those jars is throwing the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.litle.sdk.LitleOnlineException: Exception connection to Litle
at com.litle.sdk.Communication.requestToServer(Communication.java:75)
at com.litle.sdk.LitleOnline.sendToLitle(LitleOnline.java:679)
at com.litle.sdk.LitleOnline.authorize(LitleOnline.java:153)
at com.litle.sdk.LitleOnline.authorize(LitleOnline.java:145)
at com.example.LitleAuthUnedited.main(LitleAuthUnedited.java:82)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <208.70.177.61> != <prelive.litle.com>
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:220)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:149)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:130)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
at com.litle.sdk.Communication.requestToServer(Communication.java:64)
... 4 more
```

After some research I understood this has to do something with certificate issue. I tried to install Litle's certificate into "jssecacerts" file in jdk which did not solve the issue.

Also, I tried to add hosts file entry with ip and dns name mapping which did not solve.

I was able to make it work by editing Litle's jar file and adding "allow_all_hostname_verifier" during post. But, I cannot follow this as I have to edit the jar file and also this approach is not recommended.

Can any one suggest how I need to fix this?

Thanks,
Harika

Comment: Please read the question properly. I did do some research on my side.

Comment: @Emmanuel Angelo.R - Why did you vote "-1" ?

Comment: @EmmanuelAngelo.R I utterly fail to see how removing significant information can possible improve anybody's understanding.

Comment: @HarikaMamidi What part of `hostname in certificate didn't match: <208.70.177.61> != <prelive.little.com>` don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP - looking at the message the first thing that I did is to check if there is any where my logic or certificates are mapped to IP, but I could not find them anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This line in the exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <208.70.177.61>
```

Seems to insinuate you are trying to access the server using an URL like this:

https://208.70.177.61/

An SSL certificate is usually tied to a domain, often with a hostname. Try using a real hostname like:

https://prelive.litle.com/

Comment: I am using this url : url=https\://prelive.litle.com/vap/communicator/online for posting to little online. I do not have IP address mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is actually the reverse lookup at litle.com. I can resolve the hostname but I cannot resolve the IP address. Seems like litle.com does not have the reverse DNS configured.
`$ nslookup`
`> server 8.8.8.8`
`Default server: 8.8.8.8`
`Address: 8.8.8.8#53`
`> 208.70.177.61`
`Server:  8.8.8.8`
`Address: 8.8.8.8#53`
``
`** server can't find 61.177.70.208.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: I took a look at the site and it looks like Litle & Co has been purchased by Vantiv. Vantive appears to have taken over the products from Litle & Co. I would recommend getting in touch with their developer support. Perhaps the documentation is out of date and they have a new URL.

Comment: Actually, a quick glance at their documentation on GitHub shows a different Sandbox URL than the one you're using. Their documentation here: https://gist.github.com/litleSDK/2139120 says to use this URL: https://www.testlitle.com/sandbox/communicator/online

Comment: Yes, Vantiv aquired litle. And testlitle is their old url. prelive is the new one they provided to me.

Comment: OK, then your best bet is to talk to them about reverse DNS. Another temporary option is to add `208.70.177.61 prelive.litle.com` to your hosts.conf file.

Comment: I already added the domain name and ip mapping in my hosts file, I mentioned the same in the question. I am trying to contact their support team who are yet to respond to my email. I will keep updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be this:

```
hostname in certificate didn't match: <208.70.177.61> != <prelive.litle.com>
```

It sounds like the certificate lists the actual domain name of the site (prelive.litle.com) and you're instead trying to connect directly to the IP of the site (208.70.177.61), or vice versa. That explains why it works when you edit the jar to allow all hostnames.

Comment: I am using this url : url=https\://prelive.litle.com/vap/communicator/online for posting to little online. I do not have IP address mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I am using this url : url=https\://prelive.litle.com/vap/communicator/online for posting to little online. Also, I created certificate using "prelive.litle.com" hostname.

Comment: And you're still getting the same error message? Have you tried viewing the certificate to verify that the name is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, I am still facing the issue. I verified the certificate in firefox browser, Common Name is "prelive.litle.com"